# Creating a group middleware for all the admission steps in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am currently building an admission website for my project in LARAVEL. My professor suggested that I should use middleware for my steps. I have steps 1-12 in my website. Ok example, I am the user I haven't finished step 1 yet, the routes for steps 2-12 are disabled. Now, I already finished up to the step 3 of my admission but I want to go back to step 1 to edit my name so I went back. Step 3 is still enabled since it it the current admission step im doing. How do i do that in Laravel Middleware?

**Sample Routes**

```
//Admission Steps
// STEP 1
Route::get('/step1/{id}',[CustomAuthController::class, 'step1'])->middleware('isLoggedIn');
Route::post('/step1-register',[CustomAuthController::class, 'step1Register'])->name('step1-register');
// STEP 2
Route::get('/step2/{id}',[CustomAuthController::class, 'step2'])->middleware('isLoggedIn');
Route::post('/step2-register',[CustomAuthController::class, 'step2Register'])->name('step2-register');
// STEP 3
Route::get('/step3/{id}',[CustomAuthController::class, 'step3'])->middleware('isLoggedIn');
Route::post('/step3-register',[CustomAuthController::class, 'step3Register'])->name('step3-register');
```

Comment: You'd have to store the most recent completed step in a session if you want this to work as described. Also, you don't have to implement this with middleware.

Comment: tell me more, im new to laravel so i dont know the workarounds. can you please paste a link where i can read a documentation about it or a step by step guide. it will really help me improve, thanks.

Comment: so i dont need to create db table with columns named step1-12 with boolean values which updates every time the user submits a data? just a session?

Comment: You COULD do it with a database. Doing it with a database means that if the user logs out, the app would still know what step they are on. Also, instead of 12 columns, if you decide to use a database, just use 1 column with the current step number.

Comment: You COULD also do it with a session. When the user logs in, you could compute what step they are on and store it in the session. These are all implementation details and you could do it many different ways.

Comment: if i want to use the DB style, how can i implement the single column which stores the step number in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just pseudocode, but it would be something like this.

**CustomAuthController**

```
public function step2()
{
    // Check to make sure the user is on the correct step
    $step = session()->get('currentStep');

    if ($step != "2" ) {
        // redirect to step 1 with an error message
    }

    // Return the form for step 2
    return view("step2");
}

public function step2Register()
{
    // Check to make sure the user is on the correct step
    $step = session()->get('currentStep');
    
    if ($step != "2" ) {
        // redirect to step 1 with an error message
    }

    // Do your normal processing here. Validation, etc. 
    // Store whatever you want from this step. 


    // Everything was processed successfully so update the current step
    session()->put('currentStep', 3);

    // Move them to step 3 now
    return view("step3");
}
```

Also, this doesn't have to be done with `session()`. You could just as easily update a column in a database with the step number.